# Need to Add 3 Day to current Transaction Date

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a button that needs to add 3 days to the current transaction date already in `ArrayList`.

How to accomplish this?

The code is as follows:

```
private void btnCheckCleared_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Transaction item in tranArray)
    {
        if (What goes here?)
        {
            DateTime.Today.AddDays(3).ToLongDateString();
        }
    }
}
```

If you need any more code, please let me know.

So here is my Transaction.cs code:

```
namespace TEXT TEXT TEXT

{
    public class Transaction
    {
        //data hiding (blackbox)
        //visible only to class itself
        //fields (variables)
        //4 member variables (instantiate object)
        private decimal decAmount;
        private DateTime dteTransactionDate;
        private string strCheckNumber;
        private string strPayee;
        private string strTypeTrans;
        public bool CheckCleared;

        public decimal Amount
        {
            get
            {
                return decAmount;
            }
            set
            {
                decAmount = value;
            }
        }

        public string CheckNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return strCheckNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                strCheckNumber = value;
            }
        }

        public string Payee
        {
            get
            {
                return strPayee;
            }
            set
            {
                strPayee = value;
            }
        }

        public DateTime TransactionDate
        {
            get
            {
                return dteTransactionDate;
            }
            set
            {
                dteTransactionDate = value;
            }
        }


        public TransactionType TypeTrans;

        //constructor 
        public Transaction(string payee, decimal amount, TransactionType typeTrans, DateTime transactionDate)
        {
            this.Payee = payee; //assignment operator =
            this.Amount = amount; //this is to qualify
            this.TypeTrans = typeTrans;
            this.TransactionDate = transactionDate;
        }

        public Transaction(string payee, decimal amount, TransactionType typeTrans, DateTime transactionDate, string checkNumber)
        {
            this.Payee = payee; //assignment operator =
            this.Amount = amount; //this is to qualify
            this.CheckNumber = checkNumber;
            this.TypeTrans = typeTrans;
            this.TransactionDate = transactionDate;
        }

        //public Transaction ()

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.TransactionDate.ToShortDateString() + " " + this.Amount.ToString("C") + "\t" + this.TypeTrans;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you explain it bit more.

Comment: What does the Transaction class look like? Does it have a DateTime field to modify? And why would we know what you want as the "if" condition?

Comment: Well, you're operating on a Transaction, so your "if" probably needs to do a conditional check on something in the transaction class. So, your if is going to be something like "if (item.[Property] == [value]).  Also, you need to set some property of the Transaction class to update it.  You probably want to add 3 days to the current date in the class, not today. So: item.[DateProperty] = item.[DateProperty].AddDays(3);

Comment: The criteria calls for a new field to store whether a check has cleared (Boolean) whenever the check date is at least 3 days in the past., for example right now, it shows, Date Amount Name, so when the user clicks on the btnCheckClear, it needs to show Date Amount Name Cleared (Check) #.

Comment: -Aaron, You are saying that I need to update the Transaction.cs file as well to show the changes and update the main.cs as well?

Comment: Just show us the Transaction class for a start.

Comment: Alexandru - How would I proceed to show this? in the Transaction.cs file or the main.cs file?

Comment: Transaction.cs, the model is enough, no need to post any methods, just the properties.

Comment: Alexandru - See edited Post

Comment: Ok, so to add 3 days, you need to do: item.TransactionDate.AddDays(3)
Is there anything else you wanted?

Comment: Which area of the code would I add this?

Comment: In the foreach from the click function

Comment: Alexandru - I see no click function in my Transaction.cs file...There is a click function in my main.cs file...Is this where you meant?

Answer (score 0):

You need something like that:

```
private void btnCheckCleared_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Transaction item in tranArray)
    {
        if (/*Whatever your condition looks like*/)
        {
            item.TransactionDate = item.TransactionDate.AddDays(3);
        }
    }
}
```

`AddDays` does **not** modify the given `DateTime` but returns a **new** `DateTime`, that's why it is assigned back to `item.TransactionDate`

Comment: What condition should I put?

Comment: You don't need a condition if you want to update every item in your array. Only specify it if there *is* a condition which items should be updated (e.g. if the `TransactionDate` has a certain value)